# Space distance between observers and Lorentz transformation

Tags: special-relativity, spacetime

I'm not a specialist of Lorentz transformation. I would like to know if the Lorentz transformation from one observer to another preserves the space distance between these two observers.

Example (edited): Two spaceships are flying through space at arbitrary, different velocities. Two signal flashes are shot simultaneously (Earth frame) from Earth to the spaceships, which are equidistant to Earth (Earth frame) at the moment of the simultaneous (Earth frame) two explosions at the arrival of the two flashes. Each space ship is measuring the space distance between the two flashes. Will their result be the same? And, will a measurement from Earth have a different result because of the length contraction effect? (No gravity must be taken into account. In case of need you may replace Earth by a third spaceship).

Comment: Do both ships have the same velocity relative to Earth? For example as measured from Earth is ship A moving at $+v$ and ship B at $-v$? I assume you mean Earth sends some signal (travelling at $c$) and the ships do the measurement when they receive the signal from Earth.

Comment: @John Rennie Ships have the same distance to Earth not the same velocity. Transmission as you assume, I think in this way simultaneity is ensured.

Comment: @Moonraker, your conclusion that simultaneity is ensured is incorrect.  See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

That's an ambiguous question, because it depends on what you mean by *simultaneous*.

Suppose the two spaceships (call them $A$ and $B$) pass each other at time $t = 0$ and they synchronise their clocks at this moment.

- In the rest frame of $A$ the spaceship $B$ is moving at some velocity $v$, so when $A$'s clock shows time $t$ the distance from $A$ to $B$ is just $vt$.
- In the rest frame of $B$ the spaceship $A$ is moving at velocity $-v$, so when $B$'s clock shows time $t$ the distance from $B$ to $A$ is just $-vt$.

So in both frames the distance at time $t$ **as measured by a local clock** is the same. But both in $A$'s frame and $B$'s frame the two measurements are not simultaneous. Let's do the calculation to show this:

Suppose $A$ does their measurement at time $t$ so the measurement is done at the spacetime point $(t, 0)$. We want to know what this time is in $B$'s frame, so we use the Lorentz transformation:

$$ t' = \gamma\left(t - \frac{vx}{c^2}\right) $$

so we get:

$$ t' = \gamma t $$

So in $B$'s frame $B$ does the measurement at time $t$ but $A$ does the measurement at time $\gamma t$, and the two measurements aren't simultaneous. I won't go through the calculation again, but in a similar way in $A$'s frame $A$ does the measurement at time $t$ but $B$ does the measurement at time $\gamma t$ and again the measurements aren't simultaneous.

Comment: A good remark! I added an edit. Could you answer now?

Answer (score 1):

> I would like to know if the Lorentz transformation from one observer
>   to another preserves the space distance between these two observers.

As I read this question, we have

(1) two observers (reference frames) in relative uniform motion.  This follows from *"the Lorentz transformation from one observer to another"* in the above.

(2) a *"space distance between these two observers"* being the **distance between the origins** of the two frames of reference.

So, we have a frame $O$ and a frame $O'$ with velocity $v$ in $O$.

Assuming the standard configuration, the spatial coordinate of the origin of $O'$ in $O$ is

$$x_{O'} = vt$$

And, the spatial coordinate of the origin of $O$ in $O'$ is

$$x'_O = -vt'$$

This is what it *means* to say that the two reference frames have a relative velocity of $v$.

The problem is this:  $t \ne t'$ except at the event $x=0, t=0$.

So when you ask

> Two spaceships are flying through space at arbitrary speed and
>   measuring simultaneously the distance one to each other

you're imposing the impossible; they don't agree that their measurements are simultaneous.

And, indeed, even when you ask

> Suppose that measurements happen **simultaneously**. Example: When both
>   spaceships are equidistant to Earth, they receive simultaneously an
>   order from Earth to measure instantly.

you must understand that, the orders are not received simultaneously in any frame of reference except the Earth's.  According to either spaceship, the *other* spaceship received their order at a different time.

So, as written, your questions are not well posed.

Comment: I do not see any simultaneity issue. Both spaceships receive simultaneously (Earth frame) a signal, and at this moment both of them set their time t=0. As they are equidistant to Earth, both clocks are synchronized at t=0. The measurement itself is referring to t=0 for each spaceship.

Comment: I should add, as only two spaceships are concerned, their respective relative velocity is v and -v.

Comment: @Moonraker, that's irrelevant.  Only in the Earth's frame of reference will both spaceship's clocks get reset *simultaneously*.  According to either spacecraft, the reset did not occur simultaneously.  Thus, according to the spacecraft, *the measurements are not simultaneous*.

Comment: OK, I modified my question by introducing two flashes which are simultaneous in Earth frame.

Answer (score 0):

> Example: Two spaceships

... let's call them $A$ and $B$ (matching  [Einstein's popular notation](http://en.wikisource.org/wiki/On_the_Electrodynamics_of_Moving_Bodies_%281920_edition%29#.C2.A7_1._Definition_of_Synchronism.) for the setup being descripbed in the following) ...

> are flying through space at arbitrary speed

... as far as that's relevant: some particular (arbitrary but constant) speed with respect to whom? ...

> and measuring simultaneously the distance one to each other. Will their result be the same?

Yes, by definition:
a given pair of participants such as $A$ and $B$ are characterized as a system by some particular value of "*distance* (from each other) $AB$" precisely if this characterization is mutually agreeable by $A$ and $B$ (foremost; and thus of course by anyone else as well). Their value of distance from each other is one common eigenvalue of their system (wrt. the operator by which distance is measured).

(That's in distinction for instance to systems of constituents who are instead only rigid wrt. each other, i.e. which are characterized by two unequal values of [quasi-distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasi-metric#Quasimetrics); e.g. $JK \neq KJ$; or in distinction to systems of constituents who are not even rigid to each other, but moving wrt. each other.)

That's equivalent to $A$ and $B$ having been (and remaining) at rest to each other such that

- $A$ can observe at least one "ping" (signal roundrip) to $B$ and reflected back, and
- $B$ can observe at least one ping to $A$ and back, and
- $A$ and $B$ agree that the initial (signal) indications of their pings had been simultaneous, and
- that the final indications (receiving the reflections) of their pings had been simultaneous, and
- since they remained at rest to each other throughout, then can conclude that their corresponding ping durations had been **equal**:

$$\tau A[ \text{signal}, \circledR B \circledR \text{signal} ] = \tau B[ \text{flash}, \circledR A \circledR \text{flash} ]$$,

and consequently (applying the distance definition of RT)

$$c/2 ~ \tau A[ \text{signal}, \circledR B \circledR \text{signal} ] = c/2 ~ \tau B[ \text{flash}, \circledR A \circledR \text{flash} ]:= AB.$$

> And, a third spaceship would it perceive a distance contraction (due to length contraction) regarding the distance of the first two spaceships?

Well: values of distance or of distance ratios are **not "*perceived*", but measured**.

So considering some third spaceship $K$ (which had been moving wrt. $A$ and $B$ with speed $v := \beta ~ c$; and "from $A$ to $B$", i.e. first meeting and passing $A$ and then meeting passing $B$)

**and considering one more** spaceship, say $P$,

(which also had been moving wrt. $A$ and $B$; and also "from $A$ to $B$", i.e. first meeting and passing $A$ and then meeting passing $B$; such that, for instance, $A$ had first met and passed $K$ and subsequently $P$) and which had been at rest wrt. spaceship $K$ throughout, such that $K$ and $P$
**were also characterized by some particular value $KP$ of their distance to each other**,

**and if** (for instance) $K$'s indication of meeting/passing $B$ had been **simultaneous** to $P$'s indication of meeting/passing $A$, then [(it can be shown that)](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/a/110419)

$$KP / AB = \sqrt{1 - \beta^2}.$$

Or considering  **still one more** spaceship, say $Q$
(who also was and remained at rest wrt. $K$, and who also moved "from $A$ to $B$, and whom $A$ had met/passed even before $P$)

**and if** (for instance) $A$'s indication of meeting/passing $K$ had been **simultaneous** to $A$'s indication of meeting/passing $Q$ then

$$AB / KQ = \sqrt{1 - \beta^2}.$$

(And yes: that's called "*length contraction*".)

> I'm not a specialist of Lorentz transformation. [...]

That's not a big deal: the assignment of any coordinates (as far as they might be supposed to be relevant to geometric or kinematic relations), and even more the consideration of coordinate transformations, is necessarily only subsequent to the consideration and determination of geometric or kinematic relations themselves; such as the values of the distance ratios shown above.
Geometry/kinematics and physics are and remain coordinate-free.